# How to add master branch folder to github pages?

Tags: windows, git, version-control, github

Hello I have a github repository where I am writing some code and making a folder which contains some HTML.

I have created a github page for my repo using github pages and which loads data from my README.md

So now I have 2 branches:

`master`
`gh-pages`

My `master` branch has the following structure:

```
HTML/
IMAGES/
codeFiles.py
codeFile2.py
...
```

Is there any ways I can include just my `HTML/` folder from my `master` branch into my `gh-pages` branch.

What I am looking for is a structure like of my `gh-pages`

```
Images/
Javascripts/
Styles/
HTML/
index.html
...
```

Comment: Someone seems to have made something like that here: https://gist.github.com/833223

I don't want to touch that stuff, so not putting it as an answer...

Comment: @eis That's just setting up two clones of the same github repository, one for the `master` branch one for the `gh-pages` branch.

Comment: @qqx did you note the comments?

Comment: @eis Yes, I did see the comments, and even there I didn't see anything related to this question.  There while there is talk about having the working tree and repository for the `gh-pages` branch underneath the working tree for master that was still two separate clones only related in that they're clones of the same github repository.  That still doesn't alter anything about the structure of either branch in the repository.

Answer (score 1):

**Note** I don't use gh-pages myself, so I haven't tried this exact scenario.  If you do this I strongly advise doing it in a new clone of the repository and checking both branches thoroughly before pushing any changes.

You could do:

```
git checkout gh-pages
git read-tree master:HTML
git clean -df
git checkout .
git commit
```

All previous contents of the `gh-pages` branch would be removed in the new commit, replaced by the contents of the `HTML` directory from the current version of your master branch.  This would not cause future changes to that content to be synced between those branches, but you could use the subtree merge strategy to merge changes to that shared content from the other branch:

```
git merge -s subtree $other_branch
```

But this isn't likely to work as well as merges typically do in git because those branches still don't share any history, only some of the content.